# Generate Dynamic Nested Routes with Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm working on a static website based on Nuxt.js.

The website contain posts, and each post has one main category, and one second category. So I'm having dynamic children inside dynamic parents.

```
pages/
--| _category/
-----| _subCategory/
--------| _id.vue
--------| index.vue
-----| _subCategory.vue
-----| index.vue
--| _category.vue
--| index.vue
```

Wanted path : `website.com/category/subCategory/title-of-the-post.html`.

**The generation is configured inside the nuxt.config.js file, but I don't know how to create my routes based on the categories each post got..**

The documentation :

```
export default {
  generate: {
    routes: function () {
      return axios.get('https://my-api/users')
      .then((res) => {
        return res.data.map((user) => {
          return '/users/' + user.id
        })
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Did you ever find our the solution to this?

Comment: Any news on this?